# VSCode Remove function parameters autocompletion

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like that when I press tab to complete a function, to only have parentheses instead of autofilled parameters.

Before:

```
local platform = display.newImageRect(parent,filename,baseDir,width,height);
```

After:

```
local platform = display.newImageRect();
```

I have searched every settings and can't seem to find a setting that disables parameters autocomplete.

Is there a way to do so?